# How to use cURL instead of exec()?

Tags: php, curl

I get the error:

> Warning: `exec()` has been disabled for security reasons

For the following code, any ideas of how I could workaround this without using `exec()`?

```
$file = 'test.jpg';
$cmd  = 'curl -F userfile=$file ' .
        '-F outputencoding="utf-8" ' .
        '-F outputformat="txt" ' .
        'http://maggie.ocrgrid.org/cgi-bin/weocr/ocr_scene.cgi >result.txt';
exec($cmd, $result);
echo $result;
```

Comment: If there was a way around that, it wouldn't be very secure.

Comment: Can you not do this natively? http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Why don't use curl directly?

Comment: PHP has a wrapper library around cURL.

Comment: Pretty sure if `exec` is disabled, so is `curl`, are you on a shared hosting website?

Comment: In theory Curls is enabled in 000webhost or so it is advertised. I'm not very familiar with curl queries so although I could use curl_exec / curl_init i am not sure I could print out the result of the query other than using echo '$result' as above

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = 'http://maggie.ocrgrid.org/cgi-bin/weocr/ocr_scene.cgi';
$filename = 'test.jpg';

// postfields
$data = array(
    'userfile' => '@'.realpath($filename)
);

$fp1 = fopen('res_error.txt','w');
$fp2 = fopen('res_header.txt','w');

// cURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setpot_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url  ,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $data ,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60    ,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false ,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true  ,
    CURLOPT_POST           => true  ,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true  ,
    CURLOPT_STDERR         => $fp1  ,
    CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER    => $fp2  ,
));
$res = curl_exec($ch);

fclose($fp1);
fclose($fp2);

echo $res;
```